# Resizeable Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a flexible three column layout such that the widths of the three columns can be altered by a simple drag action on the edges like it's done in jsfiddle.net

On searching, I tried to implement the following

1.http://methvin.com/splitter/3csplitter.html
This was ideal for my situation, small and worked in Internet Explorer.However it's compatible with an older version of jQuery(v 1.3) as in the newer versions it gives the error 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'.

2.jQuery UI Resizeable
It comes in with a lot of by default options for a simple div element but when tweaking for a fluid layout, there were some problems.I have tried to fit in a small fiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/vjmx2/6/.It doesn't work though

While inspecting JSFiddle's page, I caught hold of http://jsfiddle.net/js/LayoutCM.js, though since it is a part of a framework, I couldn't extract it for my use.

I'll appreciate if anybody can fix or provide a link that might be useful

Answer (score 1):

You can try the jQuery splitter demo [here](http://krikus.com/js/splitter/multiple.html).

I have tested the code with latest jQuery and its working fine(Tested only in Mozilla 13.0.1).

```
<script type="text/javascript" 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script 

type="text/javascript" src="splitter.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps.